# The type or namespace name 'SPD_SendEmailWithAttachment' could not be found

Tags: 2010

I have a workflow that is triggered programatically in an ItemAdded event reciever. The thing is its giving me a  "Workflow was  was cancelled by System Account". However when I check the log file, i see the error below:

```
RunWorkflow: Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: <Error><CompilerError Line="0" Column="10" Text="The type or namespace name 'SPD_SendEmailWithAttachment' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" /></Error>     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPNoCodeXomlCompiler.LoadXomlAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation association, SPWeb web)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.LoadDeclarativeAssembly(SPWorkflowAssociation association)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeHostServices.CreateInstance(SPWorkflow workflow)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWinOeEngine.RunWorkflow(SPWorkflowHostService host, SPWorkflow workflow, Collection`1 events, TimeSpan timeOut)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.SPWorkflowManager.RunWorkflowElev(SP...
```

Please assist.

Comment: This question is very old, but the most probable reason is that the dll is not in the GAC

Comment: Or you have to be sure that the dll is registered as authorizedtype in the web.config of the web application